# Kubernetes error code 403

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new  in Kubernetes and I have a code error 403 trying the access.

```
kubectl cluster info
Kubernetes master is running at https://x.x.x.x:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://x.x.x.x:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

"status": "Failure",
  "message": "namespaces is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list namespaces at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "namespaces"
  },
  "code": 403   


kubectl get pods --all-namespaces


kube-system   calico-etcd-6629s                                      1/1       Running   0          10h
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-675684d4bb-5h28d               1/1       Running   0          10h
kube-system   calico-node-r75wv                                      2/2       Running   0          10h
kube-system   etcd-sp2013a....                                        1/1       Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-sp2013a ...                              1/1       Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-sp2013a....                     1/1       Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-dns-6f4....df-fcqvt                               3/3       Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-proxy-mpf2j                                       1/1       Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-sp2013a......                            1/1       Running   0          10h
```

everything is running..

Comment: Are you running in GKE? Local Minikube?

Comment: I thought too its a RBAC issue but I don't kow how to fix it. Where is my problem??

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like you're being blocked by the cluster's RBAC policies. The `system:anonymous` user is being prevented from listing the namespaces in the cluster. 
(Along the lines of `kubectl get namespaces`)

Running `kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-system-anonymous --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=system:anonymous` would create a `clusterrolebinding` that adds the `system:anonymous` user to the `cluster-admin` role.

Blindly elevating accounts to `cluster-admin` is *not* recommended in a production cluster but since you are new, this should get you up and running.

All clusters need some form of authorization before accessing the API-server (accessing `kubectl`) like certificate authentication. RBAC is a way to *limit* the actions that users (both human users and service accounts) can take *in* the cluster.

A great RBAC primer from the CNCF can be found [here](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2018/08/01/demystifying-rbac-in-kubernetes/) and the official [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) are great too! Good Luck!